# How can I change the color of the menu in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, background

How can I change the color of the menu in Tkinter? That is, I need to change the color of the menu, which is attached to the window through `root.config (menu = menu)`. The usual use of `menu.config (bg = 'black')` does not help.

### Code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

menu = tk.Menu(root)

#menu.config(background='black')

root.config(menu = menu)
root.config(bg='black')
file = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
file.add_command(label='GYG')
menu.add_cascade(label='Hello', menu=file)

root.mainloop()
```

PS Sorry if I have awkward English (I speak Russian, but the  Russian version of the site did not help me)

### Reply to comment

I commented out a line to show how I tried to change the background (from the screenshot this is clearly visible)

[image]

Comment: This code works as expected after uncommenting this line: `menu.config(background='black')`. It changes color of the `Menu` bar to Black. Then what are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your platform. You can't change the color on OSX, and I'm pretty sure you can't change it on Windows, either. When you associate a menu with the window using the `menu` option of the window, tk has very little control over the menu. The menus are largely managed by the underlying OS.

The way to do it is how you're doing it. If it's not working, then it is a restriction on the platform you're working on.